# Problems with join ERROR: 1054

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, lumen-5.4

I tried to use a `join`, with an array given as a condition:

```
$task = Task::join('oc_groups', function($join) use ($filter) {
    foreach($filter['groups']['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $join->on('oc_groups.id', $value); 
    }
});
```

But I get the error message :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select oc_tasks.title as task_title from oc_tasks inner join oc_groups on oc_groups.id = 1 where oc_tasks.task_date between 2017-07-01 and 2017-07-31)

The `1` is the content of the `$value`. What I am doing wrong? - The table `oc_groups` has a field named `id`.

Comment: is there any relation between these  `oc_tasks` and `oc_groups` tables ?

Comment: No, there is no relation between them.

Comment: if there are no relation between these table then how can you tring to join these tables.

Comment: For a join it is not necessary to have a relation between the tables, correct me if I am wrong. That's why I used this kind of join, and make no relation to this table in my model.

Comment: you can't join two table without relation like this .

Comment: I got your point. You're right! - But how can I solv this problem?

Comment: you can do this with out join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have any relation between these two tables so Try with out join. like this

```
select `oc_tasks`.`title` as `task_title` from `oc_tasks` ,`oc_groups`  
where `oc_tasks`.`task_date` between 2017-07-01 and 2017-07-31 and `oc_groups`.`id` = `1`
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot. But the best solution is to have relations between those tables I think.